# Is there a bijection from $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ have the same cardinality so I must construct a bijection between the sets.

I have supposed there exists a function $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ where $f$ is 1-1 and onto but I'm not sure where to begin proving this.

I doubt explicitly defining this function would be of much use, (much like how Cantor's Diagonalisation argument requires no formula as such, as it is tedius) I'm simply interested in seeing if it is possible to map every $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ to a $(r, s) \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ and testing whether it is 1-1 and onto.

I think I could use something similar to Cantor's Diagonalisation argument for a bijection from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$ but I can't wrap my head around it for my case.

Comment: The cardinality of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ is the same so there must exist such a bijection.

Comment: There's a bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^n$ in fact

Comment: You can use a similar diagonalization argument by putting the rationals on the sides of the "square" (since they are countable), much like you would put the integers on the sides of the "square" when proving the rationals are countable.

Comment: @SimonS: Well, that seems a bit circular, given the definition of cardinality...

Comment: @SimonS Whoops, I should have specified that the whole reason I'm asking this is because I'm trying to prove that $|\mathbb{Q}| = |\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}|$ so I can't use that fact.

Comment: @MikeMiller See JMoravitz's argument below

Comment: @SimonS: I'm aware there's a bijection between them. My point was that "The cardinality of $A$ and $B$ is the same" is *defined* to mean that there's a bijection $f: A \to B$, so one can't really invoke this in pursuit of a bijection.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes, of course. What I clearly took the question to mean originally before Tristan's clarification was something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For an explicit construction,

You should know from the literature that there exists a bijection $f~:~\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{N}$.  Further, you should know that there exists a bijection $g~:~\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.  Finally, there is a bijection $h~:~\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$

We have then $h\circ g\circ f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: I'm studying for an exam, so if this question is asked, I would first prove there exists bijections from $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, and $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ and then compose those functions and use the proof that the composition of bijections is bijective? That process seems quite long, is that the best way you can think of?

Comment: @TristanBatchler: What's really being said here is twofold: 1) $\Bbb Q$ is countable, 2) the product of two countable sets is countable. I think this is a fairly intuitive idea. It would be a hassle to write down an actual bijection $\Bbb Q \to \Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I understand now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just define an injection of $\mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and an injection $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by $f(q) \to p_1^rp_2^s$ where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are prime and $q = \frac{r}{s}$ in lowest terms. Do the same for $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$.

Then note an injection of an infinite set into $\mathbb{N}$ can be made into a bijection (if such an injection exists, which it does in this case), and then take composites.

Comment: An injection of an infinite set into $\mathbb{N}$ is a bijection?  Or do you mean that if an infinite set has an injection into $\mathbb{N}$, then it has a bijection with it?

Comment: this answer is wrong.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Just order the elements in the image of $f$ and then list their indices and map to $\mathbb{N}$ by these indices

Comment: the map $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ given by $n \mapsto 2n$ is injective but not bijective since 1 is not in its image, so it can't be surjective. Revise or delete this answer.

Comment: I agree that it's easy to make a bijection given an injection of an infinite set into $\mathbb{N}$, but this is different from saying every injection is a bijection.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, this comment gives a procedure to *change* an injection into $\mathbb{N}$ into a bijection; however it is incorrect to state that an injection is in fact a bijection.  Perhaps it "yields" or "gives" a bijection.

Comment: @JasonDeVito This is true, but it shouldn't matter. This injection can be changed into a bijection and then both are in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @SamuelYusim It's been revised.

Comment: @Anthony:  I agree that to someone with sufficient mathematical maturity, it's not terribly important.  But I suspect that someone who is asking the kinds of questions the OP is asking is still achieving this level of maturity.  Anyway, thank you for fixing it.  I don't mean to harp, but there is one more thing I don't understand:  in your first sentence, what is the domain of $f$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Sorry, $f$ has domain $\mathbb{Q} \simeq \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ 

I understand though, you're correct that it would likely confuse the OP.

Comment: @Anthony:  Thanks for your clarification.  You've got the +1 from me now.